# Transitivity of $nth$ tuple vectors of Lexicography ordering

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

I have read about
[Definition Of Lexicographic Ordering](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238250),
[Lexicographic Order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521739),
[Generalized lexicographic order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3940686),
[Lexicographical order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955833),
[Lexicographic ordering](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928884),
and many other related questions with their corresponding provided answers. It seems there's none about my question here:

Let $\left({S_1, \preceq_1}\right)$ and $\left({S_2, \preceq_2}\right)$ be ordered sets such that $\preccurlyeq$ be the lexicographic order on $S_1 \times S_2.$ By definition we have that $$\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({y_1, y_2}\right) \iff \left({x_1 \prec_1 y_1}\right) \lor \left({x_1 = y_1 \land x_2 \preceq_2 y_2}\right).$$
Then $\preccurlyeq$ is an ordering on $S_1 \times S_2.$ For vectors with only two entries: $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2),$ the transitivity property of lexicography ordering is such that if $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({y_1, y_2}\right)$ and $\left({y_1, y_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right)$ then $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right)$ which is proved as follows.
By definition of lexicographic order on $S_1 \times S_2$, we need to show four cases:

Case (1): Let $x_1 = y_1 = z_1.$ Then, $x_2 \preceq_2 y_2 \ \text{  and } \ y_2 \preceq_2 z_2$ and it follows that: $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right)$

Case (2): Let $x_1 = y_1$ and $y_1 \ne z_1.$ Then, $y_1 \prec z_1 \ \text{ but as } x_1 = y_1 \implies x_1 \prec z_1$ and it follows that $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right).$

Case (3): Let $x_1 \ne y_1$ and $y_1 = z_1.$ Then, $x_1 \prec y_1 \text{ but as } \ y_1 = z_1, \implies  x_1 \prec z_1 $ and it follows that $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right).$

Case (4): Let $x_1 \ne y_1$ and $y_1 \ne z_1.$  Then,  $x_1 \prec y_1$ and $y_1 \prec z_1 \implies x_1 \prec z_1$ and $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right)$

Thus, in all cases it can be seen that: $\left({x_1, x_2}\right) \preccurlyeq \left({z_1, z_2}\right) \quad\quad\Box$

QUESTION: for n-tuple vectors, $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n), \ B = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n), \ C = (c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$, how would I prove such a transitivity property using all these four cases? Could there be a better way than using the four cases to prove transitivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming "ordered set" means "partially ordered set". If $A=B$ or $B=C$, this is clear, so assume that $A\prec B\prec C$ (that is, none of them are equal). Then by definition of lexicographic order, there is some $i$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $a_i\prec_i b_i$ and $a_j=b_j$ for all $j<i$. Similarly, there is some $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $b_k\prec_k c_k$ and $b_j=c_j$ for all $j<k$. We need only consider two cases.

Case (1): Assume $k\leq i$. Then for all $j<k$, we have $a_j=b_j=c_j$ and $a_k\preceq_k b_k\prec_k c_k$, hence $A\prec C$.

Case (2): Assume $i<k$. Then for all $j<i$, we have $a_j=b_j=c_j$ and $a_i\prec_i b_i\preceq_i c_i$, hence $A\prec C$.

Comment: I assumed you prove via $\left({x_1 = y_1 \land x_2 \preceq_2 y_2}\right)$ is that correct? Again, could you elaborate why you considered only two cases?

Comment: @holala For $n$-tuples, with $n$ arbitrary, trying to prove it your way would need a lot more cases. You could have $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2\preceq_2 y_2$, you could have $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$, but $x_3\preceq_3 y_3$, and so on with $n$ different cases. There are also $n$ cases for $y$ and $z$, so you'd have to consider $n^2$ cases total. Here, we just know that there are some indices $i$ and $k$ that makes $A\preceq B$ and $B\preceq C$ respectively. Since either $k\leq i$ or $i<k$, that means we only have to consider two cases.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @holala If you agree, maybe you should consider upvoting, and eventually, perhaps accepting this answer.

Comment: How would I use your prove to show that any finite set of distinct vectors has a lexicographically smallest element? Could you also show me this?

Comment: @holala That follows from the fact that lexicographic order is a linear/total order. A finite subset of any set with a linear order will have a least element in that order.

Comment: Yea. How would one show that rigorously? Would writing three distinct set with a lexicography order be enough for such a proof? or something like this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238253 ? I want a rigorous way of proving that.

Comment: @holala It would be rigorous to prove this for linear orders in general, but if you wanted to show this for lexicographic order in particular, let $S$ be some subset, and let $x_1$ be the least element of $S_1$ such that there is some vector $v\in S$ with $x_1$ as its first entry. Consider the set $X_1$ of all such vectors. If $|X_1|=1$, then you've found the least element. Otherwise, define $x_2$ to be the least element of $S_2$ such that there is some vector $v\in S$ with $x_1$ as its first entry and $x_2$ as its second entry, and let $X_2$ be the set of all such vectors...

Comment: @holala ...If $|X_2|=1$, then you've found the least element. Otherwise, repeat this process for $x_3$ and $X_3$. If you reach $X_n$, then you must have $|X_n|=1$, since you've listed every entry that a vector must have to be in $X_n$, so you will have a least element.

Comment: Alright, noted!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to prove that the lexicographic ordering on $S_1 \times \ldots \times S_n$ is the same as the lexicographic ordering on $S_1 \times (S_2 \times \ldots \times S_n)$, i.e. that $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) < (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ iff $(a_1, (a_2, \ldots, a_n)) < (b_1, (b_2, \ldots, b_n))$.

Then, since the lexicographic ordering is transitive on pairs and every $n$-tuple can be transformed into a sequence of nested pairs, the lexicographic ordering is transitive for all $n$-tuples.